# I want to fetch data but there is some error like ORA-00904: "A.TRIP_ID": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find 2nd minimum cat1_in_flag and cat2_in_flag but in this case i got this error can u please anyone suggest me how to solve that.

```
    select trip_id,
 (SELECT T1||' to '||T2 FROM(
 SELECT cat1_in_flag T1,cat2_in_flag T2,
 DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY min(to_number(cat1_in_flag)),min(to_number(cat2_in_flag))) RM
 FROM TRIP_DTL
 WHERE TRIP_ID = A.TRIP_ID
 GROUP BY cat1_in_flag,cat2_in_flag
 )WHERE RM=2)
 from trip_mst A
```

```
ORA-00904: "A.TRIP_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 20
```

Comment: `WHERE "TRIP_ID" = "A.TRIP_ID"` --> `WHERE "TRIP_ID" = A."TRIP_ID"`

Comment: select trip_id,
(SELECT T1||' to '||T2 FROM( SELECT cat1_in_flag T1,cat2_in_flag T2, DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY min(to_number(cat1_in_flag)),min(to_number(cat2_in_flag))) RM FROM TRIP_DTL WHERE TRIP_ID = A.TRIP_ID GROUP BY cat1_in_flag,cat2_in_flag )WHERE RM=2) from trip_mst A

Comment: This is the updated query and i got same error only

Comment: Are you getting the same error? i.e. `ORA-00904: "A.TRIP_ID": invalid identifier`. I feel like this should not be the case

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT
    TRIP_ID,
    T1
    || ' to '
    || T2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TRIP_ID,
            CAT1_IN_FLAG   T1,
            CAT2_IN_FLAG   T2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    TO_NUMBER(CAT1_IN_FLAG), TO_NUMBER(CAT2_IN_FLAG)
            ) RM
        FROM
            TRIP_MST A
            JOIN TRIP_DTL B ON ( A.TRIP_ID = B.TRIP_ID )
    )
WHERE
    RM = 2
```

Cheers!!

**----- Update -----**

Updated the answer according to the situation mentioned in the comment.

Now, You can join TRIP_MST table with other tables:

```
SELECT
    TRIP_ID,
    T1
    || ' to '
    || T2
FROM
    TRIP_MST A
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            TRIP_ID,
            CAT1_IN_FLAG   T1,
            CAT2_IN_FLAG   T2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    TO_NUMBER(CAT1_IN_FLAG), TO_NUMBER(CAT2_IN_FLAG)
            ) RM
        FROM
            TRIP_DTL
    ) B ON ( A.TRIP_ID = B.TRIP_ID )
WHERE
    B.RM = 2;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Actually i have some many columns and tri_mst is main table so i can't use like that in the inner query.  And main select query the trip_mst join with some another table also so i can't use this table in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the reference to `a.trip_id` is nested too deeply for your older Oracle version. It is equivalent to this:

```
select dummy
     , ( select testcol
         from   ( select 123 as testcol from dual
                  where  dummy = a.dummy )
       ) as testcol
from   dual a;
```

This [fails in Oracle 11.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4082c32d07564ad8094e073a5c9f17bd) with

```
ORA-00904: "A"."DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

because the reference to `A` is two levels down and so it can't see it. It succeeds in dbfiddle if you change the version to a later one.

If it was clearer what data you had and what results you wanted to see it should be possible to suggest an alternative query for 11g.

Comment: This is the version issue .

Comment: I want to display second minimum data from the table and which i mentioned column so please suggest me how i will write the query

Comment: From what table? Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: suppose i have a 3 table like a,b,c.and i want to write a query by using a and b.In this query i need a two column from from c table 2minimum value . b and c relationship is b table having trip_id is primary key and c table having trip_id is foreign key.

Comment: Sample query is:-    select name,address

Comment: Sample query is:-    select id,name,location,mob_no,--2nd minimum value from c table,curr_loc,halting_loc from a left outer join b on a.id = b.id